# How do two info.plist files in Xcode project work?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, info.plist

I have two info.plist files in a Xcode project and are labeled below.  Can someone explain how these work with localization?

```
Project - EN-Info.plist
Project - FR-Info.plist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Xcode 4.6 just select file "EN-Info.plist" and in the right pane show file inspector and check english in localization section, do same thing with "FR-Info.plist" and check french